# MSI Z90A does not finish the POST routine if HDMI is not connected

Tags: hdmi, desktop, post, msi

I just got new desktop built based on https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/PRO-Z790-A-WIFI with no additional GPU (for now) but relying only on Core i7 integrated graphics.

Everything works fine when HDMI is physically connected to the monitor (it does not matter whether monitor is turned on or not). However, it does not finish the POST routine if HDMI is not connected.

I tested this behavior with multiple OSes (Ubuntu, Fedora, and Windows) and there is no difference hence I ruled out the possibility of OS bootloader influencing this behavior.

I also disabled the secure boot but no difference.

My intention to use this desktop as a monitor less server for most of the times but this behavior is a nagging issue right now.

Any help / pointers would be great.

Comment: Most home desktop motherboards actively look for a display. You may have to get a dummy HDMI https://www.amazon.co.uk/Headless-Display-Emulator-Headless-1920x1080-generation/dp/B06XT1Z9TF

Comment: This is something I did not know @Mokubai. Do you recommend any HDMI switcher we can perform this simulation if the connection is not selected. The switcher I have does not work.